# Spring with FreeMarker: Could not resolve view with name 'Home' in servlet with name 'MyServlet'

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, freemarker

I am trying to create a very simple integration of FreeMarker and Spring. However, when I run my example, I get an exception:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet MyServlet threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'Home' in servlet with name 'MyServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I don't know what's wrong with my configuration:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.jverstry.Configuration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file></welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**Web Configuration**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.jverstry")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {

        FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        resolver.setCache(true);
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");

        return resolver;

    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreemarkerConfig() {

        FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();

        result.setTemplateLoaderPath("WEB-INF/pages/");

        return result;

    }   

}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("MsTime", System.currentTimeMillis());

        return "Home";

    }

}
```

**P.S.**: Of course, there is a `Home.ftl` file in `WEB-INF/pages/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After searching a lot, not setting a prefix solved the issue:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {

    FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    resolver.setCache(false);
    //  resolver.setPrefix("");
    resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");

    return resolver;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

configuration for the freemaker (found in the spring reference documentation) 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-velocity

```
    <!-- freemarker config -->
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
  <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
</bean>

<!-- 

  View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. If you need
  different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the resource bundle resolver.

-->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="prefix" value=""/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>
```

and java config version would be :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        resolver.setCache(true);
        resolver.setPrefix("");
        resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        return resolver;

    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        result.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        return result;

    }   

}
```

Comment: Isn't it what I did in my WebConfig?

Comment: @JVerstry all fine with your web.xml