# javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name

Tags: java, spring, servlets, freemarker

I am following [this example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-freemarker-ftl-example/):

User controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    /**
     * Static list of users to simulate Database
     */
    private static List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();


    /**
     * Saves the static list of users in model and renders it
     * via freemarker template.
     *
     * @param model
     * @return The index view (FTL)
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {
        userList.add(new User("Bill", "Gates"));
        userList.add(new User("Steve", "Jobs"));
        userList.add(new User("Larry", "Page"));
        userList.add(new User("Sergey", "Brin"));
        userList.add(new User("Larry", "Ellison"));
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);

        return "index";
    }

    /**
     * Add a new user into static user lists and display the
     * same into FTL via redirect
     *
     * @param user
     * @return Redirect to /index page to display user list
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {

        if (null != user && null != user.getFirstname()
                && null != user.getLastname() && !user.getFirstname().isEmpty()
                && !user.getLastname().isEmpty()) {

            synchronized (userList) {
                userList.add(user);
            }

        }

        return "redirect:index.html";
    }

    class User {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;

        public User() {
        }

        public User(String firstname, String lastname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;

        }

        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }

        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }

        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }

        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }
    }

}
```

`*-servlet.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.epam.spring.hometask" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/ftl"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

WEB-INF/ftl/intex.ftl:

```
<html>
<head><title>ViralPatel.net - FreeMarker Spring MVC Hello World</title>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <H2>
        <a href="http://viralpatel.net"><img height="37" width="236" border="0px" src="http://viralpatel.net/blogs/wp-content/themes/vp/images/logo.png" align="left"/></a>
        FreeMarker Spring MVC Hello World
    </H2>
</div>

<div id="content">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add User</legend>
        <form name="user" action="add.html" method="post">
            Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />   <br/>
            Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" /> <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="   Save   " />
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <table class="datatable">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>  <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
    <#list model["userList"] as user>
        <tr>
            <td>${user.firstname}</td> <td>${user.lastname}</td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
    </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and got this exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'index'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1237)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Question**: what can be a reson of this exception? How to fix it?

Comment: Is it a typo? `intex.ftl` with t instead of d?

Comment: this tutorial is old stuff. i would recommend to use springboot.  you can add your dependencies to your application.  https://start.spring.io/  . just add the freemarker dependies.

Comment: this answer helped http://stackoverflow.com/a/13088628/3014866

Answer (score 0):

In controller redirection use only index instead of index.html. it will redirect to index method of controller.And you can view the output on index page itself after clicking on button.

As shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String add(@ModelAttribute ("usr") User user){

            if (null != user && null != user.getFirstname()
                    && null != user.getLastname() && !user.getFirstname().isEmpty()
                    && !user.getLastname().isEmpty()) {
                synchronized (userList) {
                    userList.add(user);
                }
            }
            return "redirect:index";
```